# Unabled to use Vuex Getter with params

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have Vuex Store that will look like this

```
const config = {
  featureA: { isEnabled: true, maxUser: 2 },
  featureB: { isEnabled: false, maxData: 5 },
}

const actions = {
  getDataCompany(context, payload) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const result = await firebase.firestore().collection(payload.collection).doc(payload.companyId).get()
        if (result) {
          if (payload.isLogin) await context.commit('setConfig', result.data())
          return resolve(result.data())
        }
        reject(new Error('Fail To Load'))
      } catch (e) {
        reject(new Error('Connection Error'))
      }
    })
  }
}

const mutations = {
  setConfig(state, payload) {
    state.config = payload
  }
}

const getters = {
  getData: ({ config }) => (feature, key) => {
    const state = config
    if (state) if (state[feature]) if (state[feature][key]) return state[feature][key]
    return null
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: { config },
  actions: { ...actions },
  mutations: { ...mutations },
  getters: { ...getters }
})
```

It's working fine with this method to get the data

```
computed: {
  featureAEnabled() {
    return this.$store.getters.getData('featureA', 'isEnabled')
  },
}
```

But I have a problem when the data is change, the value is not update in component, and now I want to use `mapGetters` because it say can detect changes, But I have problem with the documentation and cannot find how to pass params here,

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    featureAEnabled: 'getData'
  })  
}
```

I'am calling the action from here

```
async beforeMount() {
  await this.$store.dispatch('getDataCompany', {collection: 'faturelsit', companyId: 'asep', isLogin: true})
}
```

And try to detect change in here

```
mounted() {
  if (this.featureAEnabled) console.log('feature enabled')
}
```

The value change is not detected, and need to refresh twice before the changes is implemented in component

My main target is to detect if there any data change in `Vuex` and make action in component,

**nevermind** just working with `watch` without `mapgetter`,

I just realize that `computed` cannot re-run the `mounted`, so I make `method` that will called when the variable change in `watch`. thank you.

The main purpose is fulfilled, but the `mapgetter` with params is still **not answered**. so if anyone want to answer please share the way to use mapgetter with params.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use get and set methods for your computed property.
Example:

```
computed: {
  featureAEnabled: {
    get() {
        return this.$store.getters.getData('featureA', 'isEnabled')
    },
    set(value) {
      ...update featureEnabled property in vuex store
    }
  },
}
```